# Assigning a Text Format To a Dynamic Range of Cells In A Column

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble with the following code. The Code Runs and applies the Text Format to the Dynamic Range of Cells, but returns a type Mismatch error.

```
Dim k As Long

For k = 3 To 100
    
    If k <> "" Then
    
    Cells(k, 2).Value2 = WorksheetFunction.Text(Cells(k, 2).Value2, "00")
    
    End If
    
Next k
```

What can I do so the Code Returns no error?

Comment: What is `If k <> "" Then` supposed to do? Why are you attempting to compare a `Long` to a `String`?

Comment: Why not just use `Range.NumberFormat`?

Comment: The data is being transferred into into a .txt file. I already did try to use the .NumberFormat and the leading 0 in the cell  values are removed. My logic on using the long is to count through the range of cells in the for loop. The String is used for the Text Format function that I am trying to use.

Comment: Ok... but you can't compare `3`,`4`,`5`, etc. to `""` - that's an automatic type mismatch. `If k <> ""` doesn't make sense.

Comment: So do declare k as a string?

Comment: What @BigBen is saying is, you need: `If Cells(k, 2)<>"" Then`

Comment: I would also use `Format` instead of `WorksheetFunction.Text`

Comment: Thank you two for time. @ScottCraner, That solved my issue.

Comment: Any particular reason why you would do that? I would like to note it down

Comment: Format is native to vba, while the worksheetfunction is not.  And it is less typing.  There are times that worksheet function are quicker than native functions, but in general if one is in vba use vba.

Comment: so instead of WorksheetFunction.Text

Format.Text

Comment: no just `Format(Cells(k, 2).Value2, "00")`

Comment: Awesome, I went and researched it and found exactly what you sent. So, I am having another issue. When I go to format my date, and run my code for the csv file, it is still giving me Number values instead of the Short Date Value of mm/dd/yyyy. any advice with this? I can do it on excel without vba, but I want the code to complete the job for the user.

Comment: Sorry for picking your brain so much

Comment: @sjorjano - sounds like this may necessitate asking a new question.